# error javascript code showing label value as undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

guys I want to get text of as asp.net label control in javascript but it is showing me  value as undefined. I dont know where I have mistaken as I dont have much knowledge of javascript.Thanks in advance , any type of help will be appreciated.

My Code is like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function getIndex(index) {
                        var x = document.getElementsByName('lblAmount').Text;
            alert(x + ' ');
    }
    </script>
```

And Label is Like this

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text="666"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: You should see what that `asp:Label` translates into HTML or use asp.net helpers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementsByName('lblAmount').innerHTML;
```

Comment: @user2205180 see what markup is generated in browser.I think generated label has different id then lblAmount

Comment: karaxuna it has same ID i checked I have pasted code from there

Answer (score 0):

function getIndex(index) {
                            var x = document.getElementsByName('lblAmount').Text;
                alert(x + ' ');
        }

should be

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function getIndex(index) {
                        var x = document.getElementsById('lblAmount').value;
            alert(x + ' ');
    }
    </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 10
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:49419/yatra_Test/ShowResult.aspx
Line: 10
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:49419/yatra_Test/ShowResult.aspx
Line: 10
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:49419/yatra_Test/ShowResult.aspx
Line: 10
Char: 13
Code: 0
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 10
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:49419/yatra_Test/ShowResult.aspx
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 10
Char: 13
Code: 0
I am getting this error from above code in IE

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var x = document.getElementById('lblAmount').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Not working if I use with out function it works dont know y it is not able to find lblAmount in function

Comment: There was a typo, please try again :)

Comment: not Working showing these errors in IEWebpage error details

Line: 10
Char: 13
Code: 0
Line: 10
Char: 13
Code: 0
Line: 10
Char: 13
Code: 0
Line: 10
Char: 13
Code: 0

Answer (score 0):

To get the Name rendered of the control you use the `UniqueID` as:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function getIndex(index) {
       var x = document.getElementsByName('<%=lblAmount.UniqueID%>').innerHTML;
       alert(x + ' ');
 }
 </script>
```

And the `asp:Label` is rendered as `span`, so you get whats is inside the span using the `innerHTML` (not the text, or value)

The

`UniqueID` gives the rendered name
`ClientID` gives the rendered id
`ID` give's the id that you can use on code behind